# How to simplify a python function so the webdriver does't hang?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Hello fellow StackOverflow users. Currently I am writing tests via selenium and python to test the webcontent of the site I am working for. Some of the pages are dynamically filled out with updated content, so I recently wrote a function that tests the links from that content. Since its dynamic, no class names, strings, or xpaths stay the same. Thus the function retrieves the list of links after obtaining the description of a container in which the data is filled out. Here is the function:

```
def dynamic_test(self, by, target, extent):
    """Testing the dynamic content of the container from bottom up"""
    container = self.wait_for_element(by, target)
    link_list = container.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    if len(link_list) > 0:
        try:
            depth = int(extent)
            if depth > len(link_list):
                depth = len(link_list)
        except ValueError:
            if not(str(extent) == "all"):
                raise ValueError("Extent of dynamic test not recognized: %s " % str(extent))
            else:
                depth = len(link_list)
        while not(depth == 0):
            depth = depth - 1
            self.click_link_by_position(by, target, depth)
            if len(self.webdriver.window_handles) > 1:
                self.switch_to_window(1)
                self.webdriver.close()
                self.switch_to_window(0)
            else:
                self.back()
    else:
        if container.text not in self.no_data:
            print("WARNING - Non-existent no data string: %s " % container.text)
        else:
            pass
```

Some of the extra functions that it uses is wait_for_element() which also uses wait():

```
def wait(self, func, error, timeout=settings.wait_timeout):
    """Helper function to handle generic webdriver waits"""
    stop_time = time() + timeout
    while time() < stop_time:
        try:
            return func()
        except (WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException):
            sleep(settings.attempt_delay)
    raise TimeoutException(error)

def wait_for_element(self, by, target):
    """Wait for an element to be available"""
    by = self.get_by_method(by)
    return self.wait(lambda: self.webdriver.find_element(by, target),
                     "cannot find element: %s" % target)
```

And the last one is click_link_by_position():

```
def click_link_by_position(self, by, target, position):
    """Clicks on an element by the position of href"""
    try:
        iteration = int(position)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Wrong value for click_link_by_position input: %d" % position)
    container = self.wait_for_element(by, target)
    link_list = container.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    if iteration <= len(link_list):
        for index, link in enumerate(link_list):
            if index == iteration:
                link.click();
    else:
        raise ValueError("Position out of container's bounds: %d for bound: %d" % ( iteration, len(link_list) ))
```

A huge problem for me is the fact that if it tests too many links then the webdriver overloads for some reason and the browser hangs (On Firefox specifically). This prevents me from running  the function to test the links of large dynamic content.

If there is a way I could improve this code to have higher performance I would love to know the way. Also if there are any other performance tricks for QA please let me know.

Comment: Why are you clicking all the links?  It appears you click them and then if it pops open a window you close it and go back to the previous window, but if it doesn't open a window you just move on and click the next one.

Wouldn't you want to check that something happened after each click?

Comment: Ah you have a good point. I had to code it this way because the website has external links as well as links to internal modules, the latter would not open an extra window but the test would still need to go back. I will make sure to add the division in links in there.